# How can I input a dropdown feature under one of these links?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, navbar, nav

How can I input a dropdown feature under one of these links?
`import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

```
export class Nav extends Component {
    state = {
        toggle: false
    }

    menuToggle = () =>{
        this.setState({toggle: !this.state.toggle})
    }


    render() {
        const {toggle} = this.state;
        return (
            <>
                <ul className={toggle?"toggle" : ""}>
                    <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to="/aboutus">About Us</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to="/events">Events</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to="/scholarships">Scholarships</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to="/makeadonation">Make A Donation</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to="/contactus">Contact Us</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to="/login">Log In</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to="/logintrial">Contact Us Trial</Link></li>
                    <li className="close" onClick={this.menuToggle}>X</li>
                </ul>
                <div className="menu" onClick={this.menuToggle}>Menu</div>
            </>
        
        )
    }
}

export default Nav`
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean using a drop-down selector such as Material UI's Select component and each choice leading to a different spot in your app?

Select components usually have an `onChange`, again, an example from Material's example:

```
<Select
   labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
   id="demo-simple-select"
   value={age}
   onChange={handleChange}>
     <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
     <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
     <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
</Select>
```

In the `onChange` method you'd do some logic to determine where to go, and use React Router's `history` object to go there.

Get `history` object:

```
const history = useHistory()
```

Go there in the `onChange` event handler:

```
const handleChange = (event) => {
    const uri == ... use event.target.value to determine the URI to go to
    history.push(uri)
};
```

Check out the following links:

- Material UI Select - https://material-ui.com/components/selects/
- React Router history object - https://reactrouter.com/web/api/history